# ExcelDna: syntax for shortcuts

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I'm playing with shortcuts for and ExcelDna add-in:

```
    [ExcelCommand(ShortCut = "^H")]
    public static void SetBorderM()
    {
        XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcAlert, "Boo!");
    }
```

This binds CTRL+SHIFT+H.

But what is the full syntax for ShortCut?

I'm looking to bind the Numpad keys for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel-DNA ShortCut indicators should be the same as for `Application.OnKey`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx

For the Numpad keys, I think you can put the keycode in braces:

`0 {96}
1 {97}
2 {98}
3 {99}
4 {100}
5 {101}
6 {102}
7 {103}
8 {104}
9 {105}
+ {107}
- {109}`